# I want to create a binary tree using recursion. What is wrong in my following code?

Tags: c, tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct bt{

struct bt *left;
int data;
struct bt *right;
};

struct bt *root,*p1 = NULL;

struct bt* create_bt(struct bt*);

main(){

p1 = create_bt(root);
printf("Binary tree created\n");
}

struct bt* create_bt(struct bt *root){

int a;
printf("Enter data:");
scanf("%d",&a);
if(a == -1){
    root = NULL;
        }
else{
    root = (struct bt*)malloc(sizeof(struct bt));
    root -> data = a;
    root -> left = create_bt(root -> left);
    root -> right = create_bt(root -> right);
    printf("%d\n",root -> data);
    p1 = root;
    }
return p1;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? I.e., what error are you getting? Is it a compiler error, linking error, or runtime error? What diagnostic messages are you getting?

Comment: Please look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: Give us the error and we'll help.  (or some test input/outputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement: 
`p1 = root;`     in the else part should be outside of the else statement so that if `a==-1` then it returns NULL and the left/right child gets marked as NULL.
Apart from that your code seems to be correct in building the binary tree.
Hope this helps.